# Adding graphic to MapView after async operation

Tags: javascript, arcgis, esri

I'm trying to pull some json data from Geoserver utilizing ESRI's Arcgis Javascript 4.4 API. All of the components log to the console, but the view.graphics.add() throws this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: b.spatialReference.equals is not a function
    at e._projectGeometry (MapView.js:505)
    at e.doRender (MapView.js:503)
    at e.b.processRender (MapView.js:293)
    at b.renderChild (MapView.js:500)
    at b.e.renderChildren (MapView.js:290)
    at b.e.doRender (MapView.js:286)
    at b.processRender (MapView.js:293)
    at n.renderChild (MapView.js:427)
    at n.e.renderChildren (MapView.js:290)
    at n.e.doRender (MapView.js:286)
```

I'm trying to understand why what I am attempting is not working as expected, and any help would be appreciated. Code is below:

```
function fetchJson(url) {
    return xhr.get({
        url: url, 
        handleAs:"json",
    })
}
var map = new Map({
    basemap: "dark-gray"
});
var view = new MapView({
    container: "view",
    map: map,
    zoom: 11,
    center: [-84.34, 33.93],
    padding: {
        left: 320
    }
});
view.then(function () {
    fetchJson(samplejsonlink)
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data.features[0].geometry.coordinates)
        var polyline = {
            type: "polyline",
            paths: data.features[0].geometry.coordinates,
            spatialReference: {wkid : 4326}
        }
        console.log(polyline);
        var polylineSymbol = {
              type: "simple-line",
              color: [226, 119, 40],
              width: 4
            };
        console.log(polylineSymbol);
        var polylineAtt = {
              Name: "ExampleName",                  
            };
        console.log(polylineAtt)
        var polylineGraphic = new Graphic({
          geometry: polyline,
          symbol: polylineSymbol,
          attributes: polylineAtt
        })
        console.log(polylineGraphic);
        view.graphics.add(polylineGraphic);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your codes are working when I use this coordinates as paths. Maybe your coordinates from `data.features[0].geometry.coordinates` is not match the Polyline coordinates format.

```
view.then(function () {
    var polyline = {
        type: "polyline",
        paths: [
            [-111.30, 52.68],
            [-98, 49.5],
            [-93.94, 29.89]
        ],
        spatialReference: { wkid: 4326 }
    }
    console.log(polyline);
    var polylineSymbol = {
        type: "simple-line",
        color: [226, 119, 40],
        width: 4
    };
    console.log(polylineSymbol);
    var polylineAtt = {
        Name: "ExampleName",
    };
    console.log(polylineAtt)
    var polylineGraphic = new Graphic({
        geometry: polyline,
        symbol: polylineSymbol,
        attributes: polylineAtt
    })
    console.log(polylineGraphic);
    view.graphics.add(polylineGraphic);
});
```